# Azure Storage status hung on 'Resolving DNS'

Tags: azure

I have a new Storage I just created on Azure and am noticing that the status is stuck on "Resolving DNS".  Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After waiting for 1/2Hr.

I did a search and found this blog
I found this blog http://azarc3.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/azure-stuck-at-resolving-dns/#comment-74

The author suggests it is a cache issue.

I just closed the tab and logged-in again.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was fixed by hitting Refresh in my browser.  No need to log out or clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

FYI
The next day I noticed that the issue was no longer an issue.